# nginx + IIS + GET

Tags: iis, nginx

I have nginx on pc "A" & IIS with ASP.NET on pc "B".

nginx is configured like this:

...
location ~ ((Web|Script)Resource.*)$ {

```
            proxy_pass "B"/$1;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
            proxy_set_header HTTP_REFERER $http_referer;
            #proxy_set_header  REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
            proxy_set_header  QUERY_STRING $query_string;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }...
```

but requests to

"B"/WebScript?a=b&c=d

aren't able to deliver GET data (a=b&c=d) to IIS part.

Could anyone help with this?

Edit:

There's some additional info:

nginx is also configured to proxy other data to Apache, running on "A" everything is fine there (at least GET is OK).

configuration is the same as above, but for different location

Comment: Does POST data work?

Answer (score -1):

server {
listen       80;
  server_name  “B” URL; - - - - -For example here.myserver.com or www.myseaver.com

location / {
proxy_pass http://“B”intranet IP:port; - - - - -For example 192.168.1.101:80

proxy_set_header Host $host;